# Get number of commited lines via GitHub api

Tags: github-api, github-graphql

The query

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.cloak-preview" "https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=java"
```

returns a list of commits for Java language. How can I get a number of committed lines for every item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that kind of feature in the API, and I doubt it would be easily achievable, considering that involve inspecting the diff of each commit, in order to extract the committed lines (the one added/modified/removed).

You *might* possibly have more data though [Google BigQueries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/), as [in this example](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/09/using-bigquery-to-analyze-php-on-github).